# trying to run airflow and get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, python-3.7, airflow-2.x

When I started airflow I went to the login page and entered my credentials. I was hit with this error below:

```
Something bad has happened.
Please consider letting us know by creating a bug report using GitHub.

Python version: 3.7.16
Airflow version: 2.0.2
Node: 77f00a6dff27
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/views.py", line 517, in login
    form.username.data, form.password.data
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/manager.py", line 874, in auth_user_db
    self.noop_user_update(first_user)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/sqla/manager.py", line 244, in noop_user_update
    .where(self.user_model.id == user.id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

[Airflow Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKW5v.png)

Just upgraded from airflow 1.10 to 2.0.2 for stability reasons. Have it operating in a docker container to test and see how it goes. It works in the server but I can't get past the login screen locally. Other members of the team are able to but not sure what is wrong. I am using an Ubuntu WSL if that makes a difference. The environment is in UNIX.

Comment: This looks like a flask issue to me. Does the user you are testing with actually exist?

Comment: You are correct there was no user so I had to create one manually. Going to add the answer to this chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there was no user in the docker container, so I had to go into the docker container and create the user using the following command:

```
airflow users create \
--role Admin \
--username admin \
--firstname FIRST_NAME \
--lastname LAST_NAME \
--email EMAIL@example.org
```

Replace with the placeholder info as needed. After this, I was able to login and continue without issue.